# How to make an element dynamic inside javascript function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I created a function that will enable a textbox when checkbox is checked and disable it when unchecked. Below is the function that I created. But it gives me an error "txtelement is null". Below is my code:

```
 function enableDisable(chk,txt) {
        var txtelement = document.getElementById(txt);

        if (chk.checked) {
            txtelement.disabled = false;
        }
        else {
            txtelement.disabled = true;
            txtelement.value = "";
        }

        if (!txtelement.disabled) {
            txtelement.focus();
        }
    }
```

I called the above javascript function like this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chk1" runat="server" onclick = "enableDisable(this,'txt1');"/>
```

Where the id name of the textbox is 'txt1'.
What must be the problem with the above function?

Comment: Must be no elements exists with that ID? BTW, your JavaScript design looks like it's from the turn of the century.

Comment: open console and see,whether  `txt1`  is the id or it has been modified?

Comment: Look at the view-source to see if the IDs have what you expect. Also .checked is a Boolean so .disabled=!chek.checked is enough

Comment: Post your overall HTML including `txt1` mark-up

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a text element in the page with id **txt1**.

Try adding one like `<input id ="txt1" />`

Comment: It is a different field that is called txt1

Answer (score 0):

Change declaration of checkbox as follows.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chk1" runat="server" onClick = "enableDisable(this,'txt1');"/>
```

Also make sure JS is getting loaded properly. If you see `Uncaught reference error` on console for function `enableDisable`. It would be related to JS load.

I would also recommend to refer to asp.net documentation to learn more about `OnClientClick`,`OnClick` differences and how they are rendered for better understanding.